# CallKit issue with Speaker, Automatically turned On after receiving the call

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, tokbox, callkit

I'm using `CallKit` with `TokBox` and some how it is working with one bug, i.e after receiving the call, the speaker becomes active and can not be disabled by tapping on it. Call is starting with active speaker which I think is a bug, but WhatsApp and FBMassenger have used the same with their custom calling screen View, but their speaker become inactive after receiving the call, which I searched and no relevant answer I have been found so far.

In `TokBox` they provided `OTDefaultAudioDevice.h` and `OTDefaultAudioDevice.m` file from where they configured all about audio with `CallKitSpeakerBox`. Where I found following configuration:

```
#define AUDIO_DEVICE_HEADSET     @"AudioSessionManagerDevice_Headset"
#define AUDIO_DEVICE_BLUETOOTH   @"AudioSessionManagerDevice_Bluetooth"
#define AUDIO_DEVICE_SPEAKER     @"AudioSessionManagerDevice_Speaker"
```

Which has been used as following way:

```
- (BOOL)configureAudioSessionWithDesiredAudioRoute:(NSString*)desiredAudioRoute
{
    OT_AUDIO_DEBUG(@"configureAudioSessionWithDesiredAudioRoute %@",desiredAudioRoute);

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err;

    //ios 8.0 complains about Deactivating an audio session that has running
    // I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio
    // session. Looks like we can get away by not using the setActive call
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        // close down our current session...
        [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
    }

    if ([AUDIO_DEVICE_BLUETOOTH isEqualToString:desiredAudioRoute]) {
        [self setBluetoothAsPrefferedInputDevice];
    }

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        // Set our session to active...
        if (![audioSession setActive:YES error:&err]) {
            NSLog(@"unable to set audio session active: %@", err);
            return NO;
        }
    }

    if ([AUDIO_DEVICE_SPEAKER isEqualToString:desiredAudioRoute]) {
        // replace AudiosessionSetProperty (deprecated from iOS7) with
        // AVAudioSession overrideOutputAudioPort
#if !(TARGET_OS_TV)
        [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                        error:&err];
#endif
    } else
    {
        [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                                        error:&err];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Where `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker` used for all devices, which I believe is the main reason for becoming enabled speaker, though I don't know exactly. i.e

```
if ([AUDIO_DEVICE_SPEAKER isEqualToString:desiredAudioRoute]) {
            // replace AudiosessionSetProperty (deprecated from iOS7) with
            // AVAudioSession overrideOutputAudioPort
    #if !(TARGET_OS_TV)
            [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                            error:&err];
    #endif
        } else
        {
            [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                                            error:&err];
        }
}
```

Does any one have any suggestion or does any one here who have corrected that state so far?

I also believe that many like me is going through this issue.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to disable audio upon accepting a call. If that is the case, isn't it a common sense that speaker should be activated once you accept a call? If users are not ready, they won't accept it. What do you think? @Abhishek Mitra

Comment: @LucasHuang Thanks for responding, What I'm facing is, when receiver receives the call, the speaker become active(in Loud Mode) and by taping in it, it not become disable to ear. Upon receiving the call, the speaker should not be loud speaker.

Comment: When you say speaker, do you refer to a physical speaker? So, you can't mute by tapping the mute button on your speaker? I also do not understand what you refer to loud mode. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @LucasHuang Thanks for curious about my problem, I'm going to post a screenshot, hope you will get that now. img link: https://ibb.co/nnX91J

Comment: @AbhishekMitra did you find solution to this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @stan yes, I mng to resolve it.. I forgot to post the answer. I will do that by tomorrow.. and will tag you.. im not in front of mac right now. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra thank you for the quick response, waiting for your solution

Comment: @stan Hi, I have added the answer, go through it. Hope it will help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the opentok support and they took this issue seriously and due to the service was made only for video chat, they made that speaker enable in the CallKit UI for that reason. To make it disable or to use only for audio call by using their Objective C class which is namely `OTDefaultAudioDevice.h` and `OTDefaultAudioDevice.m`, then we have to comment following line in `.m` file.

`audioOptions |= AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker;`

Hope it will save many's day.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will test it in a few hours and let you know how it goes

Comment: Now on one of the devices is ok but on the other is still in loudspeaker, maybe is something with the device, I will still rate your answer as it helped a bit :)

Comment: The receiver should have got disable speaker, and about caller, i don't know actually. what are you getting for whom? @stan

Comment: It seems that it is happening on the same device ref: the loudspeaker is on. No matter if calling or receiving

Comment: @stan, Suppose I have two device, namely device A and device B, If I make call from device A to device B, the device B's CallKit UI won't show the enable speaker, if it is in audio chat only. I don't know about device A. because i have made my app for video call. but before that I have tested and it was working.

Comment: I will keep trying and will post here if any result. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have managed to solve the problem. The solution was a mixture of @AbhishekMitra and something I found myself

First I have replaced the Objective C class OTDefaultAudioDevice with DefaultAudioDevice.swift found here: 
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/blob/master/Custom-Audio-Driver/Custom-Audio-Driver/DefaultAudioDevice.swift

which is equivalent to the objc one, comment out the line Abhishek suggested and added another line in the same function namely:

```html
configureAudioSessionWithDesiredAudioRoute(desiredAudioRoute: DefaultAudioDevice.kAudioDeviceHeadset)
```

Here is the whole function

```html
fileprivate func setupAudioSession() {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        
        previousAVAudioSessionCategory = session.category
        avAudioSessionMode = session.mode
        avAudioSessionPreffSampleRate = session.preferredSampleRate
        avAudioSessionChannels = session.inputNumberOfChannels
        do {
            try session.setPreferredSampleRate(Double(DefaultAudioDevice.kSampleRate))
            try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.01)
            let audioOptions = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers.rawValue |
                AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth.rawValue
                //|
                //AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker.rawValue
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat, options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: audioOptions))
            setupListenerBlocks()
            //set the audio to headset
            configureAudioSessionWithDesiredAudioRoute(desiredAudioRoute: DefaultAudioDevice.kAudioDeviceHeadset)
            
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Error setting up audio session \(err)")
        } catch {
            print("Error setting up audio session")
        }
    }
```

This finally solved my problem and the devices were not on loudspeaker when the call is active. Let me know if you have any questions.

The objc version of this line would be:

```html
[self configureAudioSessionWithDesiredAudioRoute:
                 AUDIO_DEVICE_HEADSET];
```

Comment: Great Work Stan, I will definitely use your code when it I'll be needed, and your answer deserve up voting.